# From awk print a Specific coulumn's Value - passed to awk in a remote SSH - NOT WORKING. Attempted already "\$1"

Tags: linux, aix

```
$ /usr/bin/ssh user@server "sudo sysdumpdev -e |awk '{print \$7}' |awk '{size=\$1/1024/1024; printf("%d\n", size);}'" 
 Syntax Error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                {size=$1/1024/1024; >>>  printf(% <<< dn, size);}
 awk: 0602-502 The statement cannot be correctly parsed. The source line is 1.
```

Comment: Welcome! You have conflicting double quotes: `"sudo...printf("..."..."`.

Comment: can you pls. brief a little more with above error rectified command code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the double quotes inside double quotes:

```
/usr/bin/ssh user@server "sudo sysdumpdev -e |awk '{print \$7}' |awk '{size=\$1/1024/1024; printf(\"%d\n\", size);}'"
```

The two `awk` commands can be combined to one:

```
/usr/bin/ssh user@server "sudo sysdumpdev -e |awk '{printf(\"%d\n\", \$7/1024/1024);}'"
```

An alternative is to run the `awk` command(s) on your local machine:

```
/usr/bin/ssh user@server sudo sysdumpdev -e |awk '{print $7}' |awk '{size=$1/1024/1024; printf("%d\n", size);}' 
/usr/bin/ssh user@server sudo sysdumpdev -e |awk '{printf("%d\n", $7/1024/1024);}'
```

**Edit:** citing [dave_thompson_085](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/59699/dave-thompson-085)'s comment

While I prefer the local formatting, you can simplify the remote one to

```
ssh u@s "sudo sysdumpdev -e | awk '{print int($ 7/1024/1024)}' "
```

-- the `$ 7` is not treated as parameter by local shell but is treated as field by (remote) awk

Comment: Your answer works a Charm... Superb... thank you...

Comment: @ShyamNarayan Then you can accept the answer

Comment: sorry just newbie.. done...

Comment: While I prefer the local formatting, you can simplify the remote one to `ssh u@s "sudo sysdumpdev -e | awk '{print int($ 7/1024/1024)}' " ` -- the `$ 7` is not treated as parameter by local shell but is treated as field by (remote) awk